# NRPE: Custom script returns unable to read input, but the script works correctly, what could it be?

Tags: nagios, nrpe

I wrote a Nagios check script which receives a path as argument and checks:

> - if the path is mounted
> - if it is accessible by touching a file in the path.
> - If the mount point directory is empty

```
[root@hadoop-nn1 mass1]# su - nagios
[nagios@hadoop-nn1 ~]$ /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nfsmount.sh /mass2/hpfiles/
Warning: /mass2/hpfiles/ is mounted but directory is empty!
[nagios@hadoop-nn1 ~]$ /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nfsmount.sh /mass1/hpfiles/
Warning: /mass1/hpfiles/ is MOUNTED properly but not writeable for user nagios
[nagios@hadoop-nn1 ~]$ /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nfsmount.sh /mass1/hp_offline/
Ok: /mass1/hp_offline/ is MOUNTED properly and writeable for user nagios
[nagios@hadoop-nn1 ~]$
```

The command in `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg` looks like this:

```
command[check_nfsmounts]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nfsmounts.sh $ARG1$
```

As you see, when running the command from the monitored machine using Nagios user, the result is as expected, but when I run the command using `nrpe` from the Nagios server, it returns "NRPE: Unable to read input".

Other stuff I tried:

> - Providing the path within the script itself so no argument needs to be passed through NRPE but got the same result.
> - Providing the path within the `nrpe.cfg`, also to avoid passing arguments but to no avail.

I've edited `nrpe.cfg` and enabled debugging, then while running `tail -f /var/log/messages |grep nrpe` and sending the remote command from the Nagios server, I see these two lines in the log:

```
Dec 15 04:09:44 hadoop-nn1 nrpe[9354]: Error: Request contained illegal metachars!
Dec 15 04:09:44 hadoop-nn1 nrpe[9354]: Client request was invalid, bailing out...
```

But I have no way to know which illegal chars they were...

Don't_blame_nrpe is set to 1.
The script looks like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script checks if the provided mount point is mounted and writeable.
# Script by Itai Ganot
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "Usage: $(basename $0) PATH_TO_CHECK"
        echo "Available PATH's: /mass1/hp_offline -- /mass1/hpfiles -- /mass2/hpfiles"
        exit 3
fi
DF="/bin/df -t nfs"
GREP="/bin/grep -q"
AWK="/bin/awk"
TOUCH="/bin/touch"
LS="/bin/ls"
WC="/usr/bin/wc"
TESTFILE="test.dat"
USER=$(whoami)
NFS_MOUNT="$1"
        $DF | $GREP "$NFS_MOUNT" | $AWK '{print $5}'
                if [ $? = 0 ]; then
                MOUNTED="yes"
        else
                MOUNTED="no"
        fi
        if [[ "$MOUNTED" = "yes" ]] && [[ $($LS -A "$NFS_MOUNT" | "$WC" -l) -gt "1"  ]]; then
                "$TOUCH" "$NFS_MOUNT""$TESTFILE" 2>/dev/null
                        if [ $? = 0 ]; then
                                TOUCHED="yes"
                        else
                                TOUCHED="no"
                        fi
        elif [[ "$MOUNTED" = "yes" ]] && [[ $($LS -A "$NFS_MOUNT" | "$WC" -l) -eq "0"  ]]; then
                TXT="$NFS_MOUNT is mounted but directory is empty!"
                RETVAL="1"
                STATUS="Warning"
        elif [ "$MOUNTED" = "no" ]; then
                TXT="$NFS_MOUNT not MOUNTED"
                RETVAL="2"
                STATUS="Critical"
        fi

if [[ "$TOUCHED" = "yes" ]]; then
TXT="$NFS_MOUNT is MOUNTED properly and writeable for user $USER"
RETVAL="0"
STATUS="Ok"
elif [[ "$TOUCHED" = "no" ]] || [[ "$MOUNTED" = "no" ]]; then
TXT="$NFS_MOUNT is MOUNTED properly but not writeable for user $USER"
RETVAL="1"
STATUS="Warning"
fi
echo "$STATUS: $TXT"
exit $RETVAL
```

What could be the reason for the error "NRPE: Unable to read input"?

Edit #1:

```
[root@mon1 ~]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 10.39.21.211 -c check_nfsmounts -a /mass1/hp_offline
NRPE: Unable to read output
[root@mon1 ~]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 10.39.21.211 -c check_nfsmounts -a '/mass1/hp_offline'
NRPE: Unable to read output
[root@mon1 ~]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 10.39.21.211 -c check_nfsmounts /mass1/hp_offline
NRPE: Unable to read output
[root@mon1 ~]#
```

Edit #2:
SSL is disabled in both the Nagios server and all the clients...

```
[root@mon1 ~]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 10.39.21.211 -n -c check_nfsmounts '/mass1/hp_offline'
CHECK_NRPE: Error receiving data from daemon.
[root@mon1 ~]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 10.39.21.211 -n -c check_nfsmounts -a '/mass1/hp_offline'
CHECK_NRPE: Error receiving data from daemon.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes... the user is nagios.

Comment: Can you cut-and-paste into your question the output of manually runnning `check_nrpe -H foo -c check_nfsmounts /mass1/hp_offline/` on the server, for appropriate value of `foo`?

Comment: @MadHatter: Yes, please check Edit #1, thanks.

Comment: Mmmm.  Thanks for adding the `-a` (I never use `dont_blame_nrpe` and argument passing so am not up to speed on the syntax).  At least we know it's not how NAGIOS calls `check_nrpe` that's the problem.  Any possibility of an SSL mismatch?  (Try with `check_nrpe -n` as well.)

Comment: Done, please check Edit #2, thanks again.

Comment: @MadHatter, do you think I can use `strace` to find the illegal chars which are being transferred through NRPE?

Comment: Quite possibly, and you're welcome.  Are there any other checks on thiis client which *are* running OK via NRPE, or does this currently affect all the checks on the client?

Comment: Yes, there are other NRPE checks on the machine which are returning proper results.
I'm not so sure how to read the output of strace, but if you know how to, then you can find the output here: http://pastebin.com/ApQ1nW6N

Comment: I guess we can have confidence that the complaint about special characters is correct.  I don't see any, but it's possible that something's not printing.  I was going to ask something, but I notice a mismatch between the command in your `nrpe.cfg` file, and the command you run manually: one is `check_nfsmount.sh`, the other is `check_nfsmounts.sh` (note plural).  Is that a typo, or is there a genuine difference there?

Comment: @MadHatter, as always - You're the man :) it was a typo.. would you like to create an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you're running through nrpe is `/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nfsmounts.sh`, but the one you're testing from the command line is `/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nfsmount.sh`.  You've confirmed that this discrepancy is the source of the problem - and don't sweat it, this could happen to any of us.  A second pair of eyes is always useful in catching these deeply annoying little gremlins!

Comment: An extra pair of eyes was exactly what I was looking for, thanks again!